# removeEventListener not working as i expect

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are questions with similars problems, nevertheless I didn't understand how to fix the problem.

I need a solution for this problem: I have a onClick listener added in html document, then, in js I try to remove it but I can't.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="my-div" style="background: green" onclick="increase(event)">
      0
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in js:

```
function increase(event){

  let div = document.getElementById( event.currentTarget.id );

  let number = parseInt(div.innerHTML);
  number += 5;

  div.innerHTML = number;

  div.removeEventListener('click', increase); //but it doesnt get removed...
}
```

It's like I can't target the event listener added in the html file. How can I target it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener that is set is not `increase`, it's basically an anonymous function `() => increase(event)` to which you don't have a reference.

Since you are setting it as `onclick` attribute, all you need to do is `div.onclick = null`.

However, it would be better to not use `onclick` in the first place since it relies on the functions existing in the global scope, prevents proper separation of code and markup and also prevents securing your page with CSP (content security policy).

If you were to adjust the event listener instead in `app.js` like this...:

```js
document.getElementById('my-div').addEventListener('click', increase)
```

...then your existing code to remove the listener would work.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the *inline* event handler, since it wasn't attached with `addEventListener`, you can't remove it with `removeEventListener`. You can use `removeAttribute` though:

```
div.removeAttribute('onclick');
```

But [inline handlers are horrible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), and should be avoided whenever possible. It would be better to attach the listener in Javascript, with `addEventListener`:

```
document.querySelector('#my-div').addEventListener('click', increase);
```

Then it can be removed with `removeEventListener`:

```
document.querySelector('#my-div').removeEventListener('click', increase);
```

It looks like you're only trying to permit *one* click, after which the listener should be removed. If that's the case, it'll be easier to use `{ once: true }` so that the listener will remove itself after a single event:

```
function increase(event){
  div.textContent = 5 + Number(div.textContent);
}

document.querySelector('#my-div').addEventListener('click', increase, { once: true });
```

(note that it's quicker and safer to use `textContent` over `innerHTML` - only use `innerHTML` when assigning or retrieving HTML markup)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if the event listener is added dynamically like

```
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click',increase(event));
```

Since you have set attribute onclick to the the element you can 
set onclick=false using element reference in your case inside the function

```
 div.onclick=false;
```

Run this to check if it works

```js
function increase(event){
  let div = document.getElementById( event.currentTarget.id );
  let number = parseInt(div.innerHTML);
  number += 5;
  div.innerHTML = number;
  div.onclick=false;
  console.log("On click is set to false");
}
```

```html
    <div id="my-div" style="background: green" onclick="increase(event)">
      0
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one:

```js
document.getElementById('my-div').addEventListener('click', increase);

function increase(event){
  let div = document.getElementById(event.currentTarget.id);
  let number = parseInt(div.innerHTML);
  number += 5;

  div.innerHTML = number;

  div.removeEventListener('click', increase); //but it doesnt get removed..
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="my-div" style="background: green">
      0
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```